# Why specific rouing rule is added after VPN connection is setup on Linux?

Tags: vpn, route

After VPN connection is setup the following routing rule is added by default:

```
vpn_server_ip previous_default_gateway
```

This rule appears useless for me. Why it is added?

**Note:**

1. VPN connection is not the connection that is used to connect to the Internet.
2. `vpn_server_ip` does not belong to the virtual network.

**Example:**

In example I will use '$ route -n' notation. Before VPN connection was setup I had

```
0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1
```

Routing table afterward looks like following:

```
193.196.65.76 192.168.0.1
0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1
147.38.45.1 0.0.0.0 iface ppp0
```

So I can understand why

```
147.38.45.1 0.0.0.0 iface ppp0
```

is added. 147.38.45.1 the IP of a server in VPN. But I do not understand why

```
193.196.65.76 192.168.0.1
```

is added, 193.196.65.76 is the IP of dialin server. Maybe it's just a precaution for the case IP of dialin server is in VPN network?!

Comment: this really should go on one of the other stackexchange sites. stackoverflow is for programming related questions

Comment: What is previous_default_gateway? Could you please show an example?

Comment: In example I will use '$ route -n' notation. Before VPN connection was setup I had 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1 Routing table afterward looks like following: 193.196.65.76 192.168.0.1; 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1; 147.38.45.1 0.0.0.0 iface ppp0

So I can understand why "147.38.45.1 0.0.0.0 iface ppp0" is added. This is the IP of a server in VPN. But I do not understand why "193.196.65.76 192.168.0.1" is added, 193.196.65.76 is IP of dialin server. Maybe it's just a precaution for the case IP of dialin server is in VPN network?!

Comment: As you can see, you should append this to your original post to keep formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When explaining this, the interface name is important.  I'll create an example and explain here.

This is the routing table before connecting to VPN.  We have our primary interface in the 10.0.2.0/24-network, IP address 10.0.2.15, default route -> 10.0.2.2.  Everything occurs on eth1.

```
k@workstation:~$ ip r
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15  metric 1 
default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth1  proto static
```

This is the routing table after connecting to VPN.  The first entry added is just as your question; The VPN endpoint through our former primary gateway, through eth1.  It also adds the local network for the new IP-address I just got.  And then it changes the default gateway to be through VPN.

```
k@workstation:~$ ip r
123.123.123.123 via 10.0.2.2 dev eth1  proto static 
10.8.0.21 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.22 
10.8.0.1 via 10.8.0.21 dev tun0  proto static 
10.0.2.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15  metric 1 
default via 10.8.0.21 dev tun0  proto static
```

The route ensures that the traffic to the VPN-endpoint flows through the physical network interface, and does not attempt to route it through VPN - as that would be impossible since that traffic is tunneled through the physical network.

Even if the primary gateway isn't changed - the VPN software will often do this just in case the VPN endpoint is located on the same subnet as your new IP-address.  This is also why you can not talk to the VPN-endpoint on the same IP-address and expect "local connectivity" after the connection is established.

(The example is made using OpenVPN)